# What email services convert URLs to links?

Tags: email, email-client

Aside from the visual splendor of HTML emails - links are the only thing keeping me from sending plain text emails. They are much simpler for users *at times* and reduce bandwidth by over 50%. However, forcing my users to copy/paste or (* shiver *) *type the URL* from the plain text email is not acceptable.

However, it seems like many services such as gmail and hotmail are converting URLs into HTML links. If that's true, then for some lighter emails I could finally switch to plain text (in certain cases) without bothering anyone.

**Anyone know what percentage (or what systems or clients) convert text URLs into clickable links?**

Some users access via the web (Hotmail/Yahoo/Gmail) while others use clients (Outlook/Thunderbird).

Comment: i'd think it's clearly over 9000% :D (j/k)

Comment: Sort-of offtopic here, belongs on superuser, or maybe webapps...

Comment: @Benjol No, as a programmer this affects only me. No one else builds the SMTP apps.

Comment: It's an impossible question to answer. There are no doubt dozens of web based email services popping up every day. All the ones that actually matter will convert URLs to hyperlinks.

You didn't mention was this was for. You can ask people if they prefer HTML or text emails if you're sending out some kind of newsletter. Anyone that chooses text knows what they're missing.

Comment: Like I said, I want to know if in certain cases I can send text only knowing that 95% of all the recipients will have clients that convert URL's to links. An example would be a activation email that just contains a link. BTW, you just answered it.

Answer (score 3):

All email progams I know make links clickable, web-based and normal ones.

You should consider putting the links at the end of the mail, and use "[number]" to refer to them:

```
You should really visit PEAR[1] and friends, PHP[2]!

[1] http://pear.php.net/
[2] http://www.php.net/
```

That frees you from problems with longer URLs within the text, and it keeps the text readable.

Answer (score 0):

You must not forget one simple fact and that is every mail client make this configurable. So I for one have the option of reading / sending html emails but I don't do that. So it's totally irrelevant how many mail clients support this, the relevant question is how many *users* have this enabled.